# URL missing trailing slash does not get redirected in CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy, static-files, trailing-slash

I'm having a difficult time with CherryPy's handling of the static files. The problem has to do with the dealing of the URL's trailing slash. Sometimes the missing slash is added and sometimes it is not: the behavior is unpredictable. I'm convinced there is a bug lurking in there. The bug seems to show up when I add or remove some static files. It looks like there could be an uninitialized variable creating an undetermined state in the function handling the slash. I have put together a minimal application that exhibits the problem (in my machine at least). I'm using CherryPy 3.2.2 under Ubuntu 12.10.

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object): pass

conf = {
    '/':{
    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir': '/home/bob/www',
    'tools.staticdir.index': 'index.htm',
    'tools.staticdir.debug': True,
    },
}

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', config=conf)
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

My experimental static folder (/home/bob/www) is very simply structured:

```
/home/bob/www/index.htm         <-- This file is just <html><body>Hello</body></html>
/home/bob/www/dir/index.htm     <-- This files includes a <img src="picture.jpg"> tag in it
/home/bob/www/dir/picture.jpg   <-- Any picture will do
```

If I browse **localhost:8080/dir/**, the resulting page displays the image.
If I browse **localhost:8080/dir**, the resulting page does *not* display the image.

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe I'm not configuring the app correctly since I'm new to CherryPy.

Thanks,
Bob

P.S. I read already stackoverflow.com/questions/10276060 which has a similar problem but using Routes. I do not use Routes.

Comment: Might try enabling the `trailing_slash` tool in your config with the line `'tools.trailing_slash.on': True`.  Confer with the [Docs page](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/lib/cptools.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.trailing_slash)

Comment: @Felix, I tried your suggestion to no avail. In any case, I think that `'tools.trailing_slash.on': True` is the default. The demonstration mini-app is down to bare bones and what I'm trying to do is very basic. I wonder if other people have had this problem.

Comment: I think it's some basic confusion about the meaning of a "directory" in a URI at the browser level.  In Chrome, when I access `localhost:8080/dir` it sends the request for 'picture.jpg' to `localhost:8080/picture.jpg` Basically, Chrome has no way of knowing that `localhost:8080/dir` is a directory, not just a ***file***. It assumes it's a file, and so it resolves the path 'picture.jpg' to `/picture.jpg` (which is correct).  If however, the URI ends with a slash it seems the browser will assume "hey, this is a directory, not a file" and treats it accordingly.

Comment: @Felix, Interesting observation. I have tested this 'bug' with Firefox and Chromiun and both show identical results. I'm not an expert on this subject, but it seems to me that in this regard the behavior of the CherryPi server should be similar to Apache's. When Apache receives a request for a 'directory' and the trailing slash is missing, it redirects the browser to a new URI that includes the trailing slash. From this point onward all relative URIs work as expected. My original site uses Apache and mod_python and I wanted to switch to CherryPy.

Comment: It seems like there's a one-line hack to fix this behaviour. Look in the file 'static.py' (cherrypy/lib). At the end of the `staticdir()` function, is a statement: `if handled: request.is_index = filename[-1] in (r"\/")`  It seems replacing this with `if handled: request.is_index = True` will give the behavior you want, in conjunction with the 'trailing_slash' tool.  (It has to do with that toggle there, `request.is_index`.  Can't guarantee this is 100% safe or the right thing to do.  Recommend asking your question on the cherrypy-users group on Google Groups, you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @Felix, I'll give it a try. Is it just a matter of editing the file and try, or I need to do something else with the source file.

Comment: Yes, I just modified that one line in the CP source, and thereafter `localhost:8080/dir` is redirected to `localhost:8080/dir/`  (with the trailing_slash tool on).

Comment: @Felix, **It worked!!!** I made the changes to static.py as you suggested; rebooted the computer; and voila, it worked. Thank you very much for your help. I will test the changes for a couple of days before posting an answer to the question. Once again, thank you much for your assistance. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution

The temporary solution shown here requires a small patch to one of the CherryPy source files. I want to thank Felix Bonkoski who told me about it. I did some google searches and found references to it at bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/895/.

Here are the instructions:

Locate and edit the file static.py (In my Ubuntu machine it was located at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/static.py). Within the function staticdir(), locate the lines below. They are at the end of that function.

```
 if handled:
    request.is_index = filename[-1] in (r"\/")   <--- Line in question
```

Edit the line in question so it looks like this:

```
 if handled:
    request.is_index = True
```

and save the file.

At this point I rebooted the computer and CherryPy is now working as I think it should work.